# Refresh android application after language change

Tags: android, locale, multilingual

I am developing an app which supports two languages. There is one ToggleButton to change language.I am using following code to change locale and all works fine.

```
Resources res = viewDashBoardScreen.getResources(
// Change locale settings in the app.
DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
android.content.res.Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
conf.locale = new Locale("es".toLowerCase());
res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
```

**Question**: How to refresh whole app after language change ?

Currently I am restarting that activity in which language is changed. It works fine but is it good practice ? Or is there any other way to apply language change in app.

Any help would be greatly appreciated..Thanks.

Comment: u got solution for this or not?

Answer (score 1):

i thing you can call this function whn togal button change it's working for me

```
private void setLocale(String localeCode){
    AppLog.logString(TAG+"set location function: "+localeCode);
    locale = new Locale(localeCode);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    UserDetail.this.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    onCreate(null);
}
```

on toggel buttong change call function this way :

```
setLocale("en-us");// pass languen in whicy u want to translate 
setLocale("ar",savedInstanceStat);
```